# How to type React prop that lifts state up

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Simple React component:

```
interface Props {
  title: string;
  text: string;
  callback?: Promise<boolean>;
}

const ExampleComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ title, text, callback }) => {
  SweetAlert.fire({
    title,
    text
  }).then(r => if (r.value) callback(r.value));
}
```

Getting a following error:

```
TS2349: This expression is not callable.   Type 'Promise<boolean>' has no call signatures.
TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.
```

What type should have my `callback`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define it as a function that takes one argument

```
callback: (val: boolen) => void;
```

And most likely you need to make it a required props if you're gonna call it. And if you want it be not required - just check if callback exists, like:

`if (callback) callback(value)`

Hope it helps :)